# Concentric Cylinders: Measured Capacitance Contradicting Theory

Tags: capacitor, electromagnetism

We have two concentric cylindrical rods in the configuration shown below. They are held isolated by two 3D-printed PLA endcaps. The capacitance can be modelled as concentric cylinders using the well-known formula.

$$C=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0L}{\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$$

For our dimensions, 2a = 0.375", 2b = 0.625", and L = 27". The dielectric is air.

This yields a theoretical result of approximately 75pF.

However, we measured the capacitance of these rods using a professor's measurement tool in his lab, and it read 3pF... He then verified the accuracy of his tool by measuring a known 6pF reference capacitor.

We're struggling to believe this result is accurate since it differs significantly from well-known theory. Is there some non-ideal effect that we've failed to consider?

[image]

Edit for more information:

- The imperial units in the calculation were correctly converted to metric using a factor of 1" = 0.0254m.
- The rods were measured vertically, and care was taken to ensure concentricity.
- The rod material is steel (not stainless)
- The professor's tool measures the phase shift of a 0.1V 150kHz signal and relates that back to capacitance. I can ask for more details if that's helpful.
- The steel was sanded at the connection points and then wound with wires that were taped down to maintain tight contact.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I know it's a bit unclear from the photo, but it's the best one I had. If you look closely, you'll see the outer rod on the right side of the red endcap is slightly bigger.

Comment: Did you measure the capacitance with the rods horizontal or vertical?  I'm thinking the concentricity might be off on a pair of rods of that length supported only at the ends.

Comment: How did you measure this capacitor ?

Comment: What frequency? What instrument? What kind of connections?

Comment: just a thought. approximately 75 divided by approximately 3 is approximately 25. There are 25.4 mm per inch. Is it possible that you have a units error?

Comment: Are you certain that you made good contact between the probes of your meter and the rods? I wonder if there might be an oxide layer acting as an insulator and preventing you from getting a good measurement. You might try attempting to measure the capacitance between a rod and itself; if you're getting good contact, the capacitance should appear to be infinite.

Comment: Did you use this value of epsilon zero = 8.8541878128(13)×10−12? The units are Farad per meter. Did you convert the dimensions from inch to meter? If you used the value based on meter for a calculation with inch, you get a result 39.37 times too big. The capacitance will be only 1.9 pF then.

Comment: It could be due to losses such as leakage resistance. Frequency matters, and it wouldn't hurt to verify the integrity of the PLA parts (are they as insulating as you think?). This is in part why we need to know what instrument did the measurement, and how (what settings if any).

Comment: Are the "two" rods "metallics"?

Comment: If you used aluminum rods or tubes, how did you achieve a good metallic contact to the aluminum? There is a non conducting thin oxide layer on a aluminum surface exposed to air. Soldering of aluminum is very difficult. A screw terminal needs a very high contact pressure for a good reliable contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [calculator](https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/TylerJones/Capacitance+of+a+Cylindrical+Capacitor), the formula used is right (75 pF).

But if the external rod is not "full" metallic, it says that capacitor value is 3 to 6 pF ...
This confirms your measure (outer radius quasi "infinite" or not wired).

Comment: It turns out there were some metallic filings between the capacitor electrodes causing intermittent shorting. Therefore, we were effectively measuring a single electrode capacitor and this answer gave an important clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confident in the accuracy of the equation for capacitance. I would investigate measurement error and the possible contribution of parasitics.

I would expect lack of concentricity to increase the capacitance not decrease it.

(Aaand...make sure you had the units right in your calculation).